# Is await with Task.Run (NonAsyncMethod()) any better?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Let us say, I have a call like this:

```
await Task.Run(async() => SomeLongRunningNonAsyncMethod());
```

My understanding is when SomeLongRunningNonAsyncMethod() is called, the call doesn't return until it encounters await. But there is no await in SomeLongRunningNonAsyncMethod().

So, is this same as direct SomeLongRunningNonAsyncMethod() call?

Comment: No it is not.. if I understand the question right.. Can you please elaborate on what are you looking for?

Comment: your title might need improvement. "Any better" than what?

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is when `SomeLongRunningNonAsyncMethod()` is called, the call doesn't return until it encounters await. But there is no await in `SomeLongRunningNonAsyncMethod()`.

You need to distinguish between the `delegate` you pass to `Task.Run` and the actual execution of `Task.Run`

The former will execute synchronously inside a `ThreadPool` thread. You dont need to use the `async` keyword as you are not awaiting on any async operation inside the given delegate.

The latter will hit its `await` when `Task.Run` begins to execute and yield control back to the calling method until the delegate finishes execution.

> So, is this same as direct SomeLongRunningNonAsyncMethod() call?

No. A direct call would execute synchronously on the **current running thread**. Your code executes the delegate synchronously on a **`ThreadPool` thread**, meanwhile the thread the call to `Task.Run` awaits the completion of the `Task` in a **non-blocking** fashion.

Your code should actually be:

```
await Task.Run(SomeLongRunningNonAsyncMethod);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is indeed flawed.

As the code execution gets to the `await Task.Run`, it will first execute `Task.Run` as usual (which will queue the method on the thread pool), and then return immediately. When the method inside the `Task.Run` finishes, the execution will continue after the `await`.

Whether this is useful or not depends heavily on your context. For example, if you're calling this from an event handler in a WinForms / WPF application, this is indeed a good way to avoid blocking the UI thread while doing some background work. If you're doing this in a web application, you're just causing a thread switch and a thread pool thread for no reason.

If you're doing I/O in the `Task.Run`, rather than CPU work, you want to find an asynchronous API to do the same I/O work - this will save you the thread that would block anyway while the I/O request completes.

Answer (score 0):

The `await`keyword will cause control to be returned to the calling method as soon as the call to `Task.Run` returns. That call returns "immediately" (it will only schedule the operation using the current task scheduler, not wait for it to complete). Once the task is completed, the code following the `await` line will continue executing.